# ChainCertificate from file

Tags: c#, x509certificate2

I have problem with certificate validation. I have .perm file witch is chain certificate file (inside there is multiple BEGIN and END CERTIFICATE).

I try to import certificate collection but after importing collection is length 1.

```
X509Certificate2Collection collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
collection.Import(certpath);
```

I couldn't see any interesting options in

```
X509Chain chain2 = new X509Chain();
```

I get return of verification false and i believe that the reason is that not all certificates has been loaded.

Below is my full validation method

```
    private static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        try
        {
            string certpath = "actual path";

            X509Certificate2Collection collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
            collection.Import(certpath);

            X509Chain chain2 = new X509Chain();
            foreach(X509Certificate2 c in collection)
            {
                chain2.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(c);
            }

            // Check all properties
            chain2.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.NoFlag;

            // This setup does not have revocation information
            chain2.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;

            // Build the chain
            chain2.Build(new X509Certificate2(certificate));

            // Are there any failures from building the chain?
            if (chain2.ChainStatus.Length == 0)
                return true;

            // If there is a status, verify the status is NoError
            bool result = chain2.ChainStatus[0].Status == X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError;

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `X509Certificate2Collection` and the `Import` method does not support the file that contains multiple certificates (appended one after another). See documentation for this method [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148497(v=vs.110).aspx).

There is one format which might work - `SerializedStore` but the documentation does not state much about it. I assume that it is some king of aray of `SerializedCert` which is a certificate with it properties therefore even this format does not match with what you have.

Try to separate the certificates and use [this constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148475(v=vs.110).aspx) to initialize `X509Certificate2Collection`.